# How do you find the equation of a tangent line to a vector valued function through a point not on the function?

Tags: vectors

Lets say we have a point in 3D space, say (x, y, z). Let's also say we have some vector-valued function, say f(t). How can we find the equation of a line tangent to the vector valued function s.t. it goes through the given point?

Comment: WLOG $x=y=z=0$. Now consider the points for which $f(t)$ is parallel to $\dot f(t)$.

Comment: And for that purpose find the zeroes of the Gram-Determinant of $f$ and $\dot f$.